# Nginx Http Health Check Fails

Tags: nginx

While setting a system with Consul and Nginx Plus for testing on couple of Centos 7 VMs, I managed to manually configure Nginx as a Load Balancer for two different services.
Each service is a simple Nodejs http server that has a unique listening port and returns "Hello World from Service=X, port=Y". I'm running three service instances on each machine (total of six).

All is working fine and load balancing is working as expected.
But now I'm adding health_check for one upstream but getting an error in Nginx error.log:

```
2018/12/05 16:52:20 [error] 17542#17542: *784 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 172.1.2.3, server: , request: "GET /ua HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://useradmin/ua", host: "10.1.2.3"
```

The nginx.conf file looks like this:

```
user nginx;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    #
    # DNS resolving using Consul
    resolver localhost:8600 valid=30s;
    resolver_timeout 2s;

    # ...
    # Configuration of the server group
    upstream useradmin {
    zone useradmin 64k;

        server app1.node.consul:8080 resolve;
        server app1.node.consul:8081 resolve;
        server app2.node.consul:8080 resolve;
    }
    upstream search {
        zone search 64k;

        server app1.node.consul:8180 resolve;
        server app2.node.consul:8180 resolve;
        server app2.node.consul:8181 resolve;
    }

    match hello {
        status 200-399;
        header Content-Type = text/html;
        body ~ "Hello";
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        # Location that proxies requests to the upstream group
        location /ua {
            proxy_pass http://useradmin;
            health_check interval=10 fails=3 passes=2 match=hello;
        }

        location /search {
            proxy_pass http://search;
#            health_check interval=5s match=hello;
        }
    }
}
```

I've read all the Nginx docs about health checks but no clue to what might be wrong. Am I missing something???

Thanks!

Comment: Any logs from your app saying that it got the health check request?

Comment: Yes, I can see that my app is getting a request and returning a valid response. However, Nginx is reporting a failure. I am using now consul-template to change the Nginx configuration to contain only healthy services, but I was just wondering why the Nginx health checks are not working as expected...